# iOS Tesseract not recognizing

Tags: ios, swift, tesseract

I have this image: [image: img]

I am trying to recognize those letters with Tesseract but I always get some random text like *_u_i.i_1, L_n_.t*. Here is my code:

```
let tesseract = G8Tesseract.init(language: "eng")
if let tes = tesseract{
   tes.image = img.g8_blackAndWhite()
   tes.engineMode = .cubeOnly
   tes.pageSegmentationMode = .auto
   tes.maximumRecognitionTime = 60
   tes.recognize()
   //...
}
```

I've found this code at [here](http://raywenderlich.com) and it works fine for them. Of course I was prepared for having worse results because I'm not using a perfectly lighted image but I don't know why I don't get any good results at all.
Any idea?

Comment: Seems like Tesseract's recognizing the darkest parts of your image, i.e. the shapes bordering your text.

Comment: Maybe. But now I tested with a huge white image with 123 in the center and it could recognize it. In fact, I've seen no good results at all since I've implemented tesseract in my project (2 days ago) scanning through everything (screen, papers, phones.. etc.)

Comment: So, if it could recognize it when you had text on a white background, isn't that the desired result?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this link https://github.com/BradLarson/GPUImage . After that add below code for tessdata langauges store. I think it will help you.

```
 func storeLanguageFile() throws{
    var fileManager: FileManager = FileManager.default
    let nsDocumentDirectory = FileManager.SearchPathDirectory.documentDirectory
    let nsUserDomainMask = FileManager.SearchPathDomainMask.userDomainMask
    let docDirectory = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(nsDocumentDirectory, nsUserDomainMask, true)[0] as NSString
    let path: String = docDirectory.appendingPathComponent("/tessdata/eng.traineddata")
    if fileManager.fileExists(atPath: path){
        var data: NSData = NSData.dataWithContentsOfMappedFile((Bundle.main.resourcePath?.appending("/tessdata/eng.traineddata"))!)! as! NSData
        var error: NSError
        try FileManager.default.createDirectory(atPath: docDirectory.appendingPathComponent("/tessdata"), withIntermediateDirectories: true, attributes: nil)
        data.write(toFile: path, atomically: true)
    }
}
```